# How does "backdrop-filter: revert-layer" work?

Tags: html, css

As far as i understand, it should revert all css properties to those of a layer before. I tried to make a custom cursor that would look like a circle that changes color palette of a page inside of itself.

This is what i came up with.
The idea is that text that gets inside the cursor changes it's color from blue to red.

HTML:

```
hello
<div class="cursor"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@layer base, special;

@layer base{
  body{
    color: red;
  }
}

@layer special{
  body{
    color: blue;
  }
  .cursor{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    backdrop-filter: revert-layer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
const $cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
  $cursor.style.top = e.clientY+"px";
  $cursor.style.left = e.clientX+"px"
})
```

Comment: According to [the compat table](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert-layer#browser_compatibility) `revert-layer` is only supported in Firefox 97+. I wouldn't use it yet.

Comment: @AKX Well, I use Firefox 110.0, so it should work, but it doesn't, which is why I'm asking how it works

Comment: @AKX - I don't understand the compatibility table. revert-layer works fine on chromium and webkit, and has done so for some time. Not sure what that compatibility table is testing.

Comment: @Relenel - `backdrop-filter: revert-layer;` will only revert the backdrop-filter, but you're not setting the backdrop-filter in any other layer.

Comment: @Alohci Oh, I see. So it reverts the backdrop-filter value to that of previos layer. I thought it would revert the properties of other elements that go under cursor. If so, how should I implement such cursor?